# L3 switching and broadcast

Tags: switching, broadcast

I don’t know is this the right way to ask this question. But anyway my question is when we configure L3 switchport as a routed port and it’s connected to a another L3 switch. Does that routed port forward broadcast traffic from it.

Please someone help me with this question.
Thanks

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 5):

Routed ports do not forward broadcasts.  Broadcast domains are layer 2 constructs and do not cross layer 3 boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Ron's answer:

There are two different broadcast types for IPv4:

- the *limited broadcast* to `255.255.255.255` that generally cannot be forwarded to another subnet
- the *directed subnet broadcast* with the subnet prefix and all host bits as `1`, e.g. `192.168.0.255` for `192.168.0.0/24` - directed broadcast aren't forwarded *by default*, but many routers and L3 switches can be configured to do so.